# slideToggle(): there is no sliding

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I just trying to slide the content of the second row when i press in the first row. I'm using slideToggle("slow") but there is no slide (no animation), it just toggle the second row straight and it takes toooo much time..

Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/7LH3p/4/

Thanks

Comment: Please post you code also here on SO. This way it may still be useful to other users when the link goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `display: block` on the elements for `slide` to work. `tr` elements are by default not block elements so you need to specify this explicitly in your css with:

```
tr
{
    display: block;
}​
```

Comment: thanks, but now my problem is that I when i convert the <tr> to block, the td's inside are in the same column (the first)

Comment: They are not exactly in the same column. They appear to be. To prevent that you need to set the width of each column by specifying rules in css. You could do `td { width: 190px; }​` which would make all widths the same or you could make a class for the each column and specify the widths or you can use jQuery `$('tr td:nth-child(n)')` to select the nth column and style it.